# How to bundle SQL Server Database with my VS2010 solution

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I am currently working on a sample website proof of concept and planning to provide the entire VS2010 (ASP.NET and C#) solution to the company. I also use SQL Server and need to provide the database (tables(including some records) and stored procedures). What is the easiest way to ensure that I can bundle the database along with my VS2010 solution? Please provide some steps if possible.

Comment: I ended up generating scripts. The option to retain the table rows is to do a back up and then restore. I was unable to post that as an answer and getting an error message. Soon I will post it as an answer. If someone has better ways do let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At my company, we actually take the same approach that you're taking, and just do everything with scripts by hand for deployment.  However, we do this mostly because we have a large legacy database, and we do incremental updates for a system that has to always be online.

If you're starting a new website from scratch, you might look into Database Projects inside of Visual Studio.  It also has some functionality for unit testing your database built in that might be beneficial.

http://www.visualstudiotutor.com/2010/08/manage-database-projects-with-visual-studio-2010/